# Indian comic book about a guy who tries to become immortal but ends up as a living skeleton

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading an Indian comic in the 90s about a guy who wants to become immortal but he might be a nice guy from start. He goes to a Himalaya-like place to meet a monk who taught him a mantra to get immortality, which needed to be chant continuously.

He starts chanting the mantra but then a landslide happens and he dies but not really. He become like a Ghostrider-thing (skeletonish with fire) and tries to do good things like a superhero does.

It was later revealed that the monk tricked him as he knows that guy's natural death would occur before he can even complete the chant. So he didn't help in becoming immortal but I think the monk was unaware that he can become this undead thing.

The guy went to the monk to confront him at one point too. It looked like some kind of unofficial ripoff of Ghost Rider marvel comics.

---

- This whole story occur in a single small comics print and must be #1 of the series but not sure if story progressed further or canceled.
- **Language:** Hindi (must be translated in English too or vise versa)
- **Country:** Most probably India
- **Release year:** must be late 80s to early 90s.

Comment: “a guy who wants to become immortal but he might be a nice guy from start” — Hey! I want to become immortal too, that doesn’t make it surprising that I’m a nice guy!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In Indian mythology Asura always wanted to become immortal and they were bad people mostly, but feel free to take that part out if you feel so

Comment: Those Asura. Always ruining it for the rest of us perfectly-innocent aspiring-immortals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be [Vidyut Manav](https://www.ebay.com/itm/394361473829)?

[image: cover: flaming skeleton stomping on tanks]

It's the only answer matching Indian Ghost Rider, being printed in Hindi in the 90's. The rest of the details I cannot confirm, like the main storyline.

Apart from it being printed by Goyal comics, not much information about the comic is on the internet.

Comment: Not able to find the story about it to verify if it's a 100% match or not but it sounds like a match so accepting.